# Does netbeans support coloring for .sh (bash) scripts?

Tags: bash, netbeans, colors

I use netbeans 6.8 beta and when i load .sh (bash) file it's not colored at all. i can add a new file association for the .sh extension but it doesn't seem that there is a known associated mime type.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I have not tried this myself but you can get shell script support in Netbeans if you install the **C/C++ plugin**.

Comment: i already have netbeans packages with everything including c/c++.

Comment: i installed netbeans on my mac and i noticed that it does color bash scripts (.sh files). in my linux box i compiled netbeans from sources. maybe i missed some plugin related flags on compilation (under gentoo). i'll check that out. thanks!

Comment: works for me, but how about bash scripts without an extension?

Comment: NetBeans only recognizes files by name (mostly by extension).

Comment: For sh and bash files without extension there is a netbeans-noext-mime-resolver plugin

Comment: FWIW I just installed the C++ plugin (Tools > Plugins) on macOS (PHP profile of NetBeans) and it works. My file had no extension (`.bash_aliases`) but started with `#!/bin/bash` and that seems to trigger the bash formatting! Thanks 

Comment: Cool. In NetBeans 8.2, all I had to do was install the C/C++ plugin, restart NetBeans, and reopen my .sh files.

Answer (score 29):

old question, time for an update  **(tested for 8.0.2,8.1,8.2)**.

Here's what worked for me

1. **Install C/C++** plugin. 
   This will recognize .sh extensions as bash files
2. **Install nb-noext-mime-resolver** (for 8.2 you'll find it as  [No Extension MIME Resolver](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/55076/no-extension-mime-resolver)) . This will add support for files with no extension by recognizing the shebang line
3. **Go to tools/options/editor/spellchecker and uncheck 'Script and make comments'.**(not available after 8.2) This will get rid of the red squiggly lines that appear under 'usr' and other legitimate notations in the shebang line and elsewhere.

You'll get full syntax highlighting as well as the ability to right click and select 'run' which will launch your script in the built in terminal. very nice.

*To get the context menu 'run' to work with your shell*

1. Select 'Run'/'Set Project Configuration'/'Customize'
2. Click 'New' and add a name for your shell like 'bash' or 'cygwin'
3. Select 'Run As' 'Script (run in command line'
4. Where it says 'Php Interpreter' (or equivilent) add the path to your bash shell. e.g: C:\cygwin\bin\bash.exe
5. Click 'ok'.

Also, check out the properties of the bash files and you'll find some helpful ones.

Comment: As Oct 2017 on NetBeans 8.2: I only had to install the C/C++ plugin and restart the IDE but the details about noext plugin is very usefull to know, Saved me an headache

Answer (score 0):

This is very odd. I have NB6.8beta installed with the C/C++ plugin. When I open a .sh file I *do* see syntax high lighting. Quotes strings show up in orange, commands are in blue.

Comment: under tools -> options -> Miscellaneous -> Files
under file extension sh what is the associated file type (mime) ?

Comment: Again, very old question, but for anyone stumbling across this the MIME type for sh on NB 8.2 (and previously) is Shell Scripts (text/sh).