# How can I get `syntax highlight` for batch command line cli .bat and .sh in Netbeans PHP IDE?

Tags: netbeans, syntax-highlighting

Currently Netbeans PHP 7.1 RC2 doesn't support syntax highlight for .sh and .bat file.

How can I get synstax of those file types highlighted?

Answer (score 3):

See the answer for the duplicate "[does netbeans support coloring for .sh (bash) scripts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636765/does-netbeans-support-coloring-for-sh-bash-scripts)". That answer is valid for both .sh and .bat syntax highlighting (I've tested and verified with 7.1 RC2).

C/C++ support can be installed via `Tools|Plugins...` on the *Available Plugins* tab, if you don't already have it (which you don't if you downloaded the PHP-only version).